# How to remove additional tab on product page magento

Tags: magento, layout, magento-1.7

I want to know How to remove additional tab on magento product page. I have using Ultimo theme on magento 1.7.0.2
I try to search from previous post but still can't remove it.

I have add additional information to a product description and change a name to "ข้อมูลสินค้า"
My point is remove a second tab but still show information on "Product description

This is my product page. http://www.siameyewear.com/ray-ban-rb3025-001-58-aviator-large-metal.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd create local.xml file inside your theme folder app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme] (if you haven't already)

And insert the following lines there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>product_additional_data</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```

After that clear the cache.
If you prefer to edit XML in separate files (which I'm not), find catalog.xml of your theme.
find the following line and comment them (`<!-- -->`)

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
```

Comment: Ohhh That help Thank you
just remove this line on app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/layout/local.xml
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>

Answer (score 1):

Are you create new attribute for product description .remove any one of the product attribute.

you can remove your attribute in your magento admin page .

> Catalog->attributes->manage attributes

select your attribute you want to delete.

OR

open your attribute check "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" change yes to no

Answer (score 0):

I am using my module adminhtml layout xml to add or remove tabs (you could use your theme's local.xml, based on these steps with a bit of tweakking.)

Firstly you will need to declare your layout updates (in your module config.xml) like the following:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule>
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Then in mymodule.xml, add the following (here, I am using the admin order view page handle)

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="removeTab">
            <name>order_shipments</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addTabAfter">
            <name>order_shipments_mymodule</name>
            <block>mymodule/adminhtml_order_shipments</block>
            <after>order_creditmemos</after>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>order_receipts</name>
            <block>mymoduled/adminhtml_order_recp</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view
```

Hope this helps!! (Don't forget to upvote this solution)